# Fullstack time tracker

Tags: reactjs, mern

I have built a time tracker using vanilla JS, HTML, and CSS, and will re-write it in ReactJS. The application functionality involves tracking my work sessions/breaks during a day, where I have a control over when to start the clock, take a break, and end the clock. I would like to build a MERN fullstack app so that I can retrieve my sessions/breaks (and other details) for each day (or a specific range of days).

What I am not sure about is the time itself. Is it better to track the time at the frontend and send it to the backend each second, or calculate the time at the backend and send it to the frontend each second? I would like the time tracking to keep running even if the page is reloaded, refreshed, closed, which may point to the latter approach, but also the front-end can retrieve the last time update and calculate the difference between that time and now to update the timer.

Comment: What do you mean with " ... send it to the backend each second"? Do you intend to send the currently tracked time to the backend each second? Why not send a start and end timestamp and let the backend calculate the time of the session / breaks?

Comment: But what if the page is refreshed and the timer is interrupted? I would like the timer to keep running in that case, too.

Comment: There should be multiple ways of doing this. For example, you could start a session whenever a user starts a timer and end the session when the user stops the timer. Even when refreshing, the session still holds. If you want to allow users to retrieve the last couple tracks you'd need some kind of user management I guess.

Comment: But I also want to display the time progression at the frontend. I am thinking maybe there should be a flag at the backend to know what's the state of the timer (playing/not, session/break), and when the page reopens it should first check this flag to retrieve the last timestamp of the activity/inactivity and do the calculation at the frontend to compensate the time difference (from the current time when the page opens again), or to start from scratch.